# The memory section in the graphics tab in CPU-Z is grayed out

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, vram, cpu-z

I wanted to figure out how much VRAM my system had but I was unable to because in CPU-Z, the Memory section in the Graphics tab is grayed out.

[image: here's a screenshot of what im talking about]

I don't exactly know why but if anyone can tell me another way to check my VRAM, or a way to make it not greyed out, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: For integrated graphics you can check at BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: A quick method of checking how much memory that the GPU is using on Windows 10 is going into the Task Manager, then the performance tab, then Memory, then looking at the Hardware Reserved value. It shows how much memory is "not usable" by Windows due to hardware; this includes other devices though.

Answer (score 3):

From your screenshot: Intel HD graphics.

That is a GPU build into a combined CPU & GPU package. Usually without any dedicated graphics memory, which means the answer is 'none'. There is no dedicated video memory. No special dual access VRAM chips/GDDR modules/...

However:

1. The GPU is sharing **main memory**. And usually has a maximum of main memory which can be shared. This is often configured in the firmware (UEFI or BIOS).
2. There are a few exceptions where Intel CPU+GPU chips do come with their own memory. E.g. Iris pro graphics 5200 might have its own 128MB of memory. These are relatively expensive chips and you probably knew it if you had one.